# ActiveMQ - A message sent to multiple queues is getting stuck in queues if exception occurs in any queue

Tags: activemq-classic, dead-letter, virtual-topic

I'm am using Virtual Destinations to implement Publish Subscribe model in ActiveMQ 5.15.13.

I've a virtual topic `VirtualTopic` and there are two queues bound to it. Each queue has it's own redelivery policy. Let's say `Queue 1` will retry message 2 times in case there is an exception while processing the message and `Queue 2` will retry message 3 times. Post retry message will be sent to deadletter queue.

I've observed that when a message is sent to `VirtualTopic`, it is delivered to both the queues.
I'm facing an issue where if the consumers of both queues are not able to process the message successfully. The message destined for `Queue 1` is moved to deadletter queue after retrying for 2 times. My expectation is that message in `Queue 2` would be deadlettered after 3 retries. But the message is retried to consumer of `Queue 2` only for 2 times and then is stuck in `Queue 2` as pending message.

There is no specific configuration I've done in activemq broker and the redelivery policy is applied programmatically. Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Comment: How are you configuring the `redelivery policy` on your `Queue 2` consumer? Can you add the code? Are both `Queue 2` consumer and `Queue 1` consumer on the same microservice or in different microservice?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both the queues are consumed in same microservice. The problem was in my implementation as for queue2, a new factory instance was created and redelivery policy was not getting setup correctly. The default redelivery policy (max redeliveries=6, with some delay) kicked in which caused delay in redelivered message. I was testing the behaviour using junit test cases and the consumer died as soon as test case was finished but message was still pending for redeliveries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my implementation as for queue2, a new factory instance was created and redelivery policy was not getting setup correctly. The default redelivery policy (max redeliveries=6, with some delay) kicked in which caused delay in redelivered message. I was testing the behaviour using junit test cases and the consumer died as soon as test case was finished but message was still pending for redeliveries.